# Javafx in jar can not open new scene

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

In my application from main controller i try to open new scene

```
public void runReportParserWindow() throws IOException {

    System.out.println("Open report parser window");
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();      
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("../views/reportWindow.fxml"));
    ControllerReportParser controller = new ControllerReportParser(getPrimaryStage(), getMainApp());
    controller.registerObserver(this);
    fxmlLoader.setController(controller);
    Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setTitle("Get data for report");
    stage.setScene(scene); //scene
    stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
    stage.initOwner(getPrimaryStage());

    stage.show();
}
```

If i run application in Intellij idea - all window open fine. When i create JAR file (artifacts) i can not open any window except main.  The main scene is shown, but other are not.
Settings for artifact 
[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841062/javafx-resource-cannot-be-loaded-when-running-from-jar help?

Comment: Run the jar from a shell with java -jar bla.jar, likely an exception is happening which you will then see.

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38444852/javafx-image-not-found-in-jar-file?

Comment: first - may be. I try to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot  **James_D**
I used relative paths for load fxml-files.
Now i replace views folder to controllers and change code from

```
fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("../views/reportWindow.fxml"));
```

to

```
fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("views/reportWindow.fxml"));
```

and all work fine.